# Couldn't start vimrun.exe on shutdown on Windows

Tags: windows, vim

I wrote the following code in .vimrc to save last session of vim. Normally, it works. But when shutting down Windows, it doesn't work correctly according to the error of failure about starting vimrun.exe.

```
au VimLeavePre * call xolox#session#auto_save()
```

The `auto_save` methods uses `vimrun.exe`. As you know, it happens because Windows prohibit a new process to start on shutdown.

Is there any way to avoid the failure?

Windows 7 x64
gvim.exe 7.4

Comment: just curious...why are you using `xolox#session`? the `mksession` command works just fine for most cases.

Comment: Because default `mksession ` couldn't work well with NERDTree in some cases.

Comment: you should try [vimpanel](https://github.com/mihaifm/vimpanel)...I made it to resolve some of the limitations of NERDTree...such as session support.

Comment: Thanks, hihai. I must try it!

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's no arguing with Windows, right?!

As mentioned in the comments, you could move away from the plugin to native `:mksession`, but you'd lose all the plugin functionality (which I use and like, too).

You could ask the plugin's author for a lightweight `auto_save()` fallback that doesn't need to shell out.

Or avoid the problem altogether by saving earlier and more frequently. In GVIM, the `FocusLost` event would work well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try `FocusLost` or try to find the way not to shell out.